# MacOS application launch event?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

I want to collect statistics for applications runned in OS.

So I need to get any events of app start and exit

Is there exist some?

Google say nothing =(

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspacedidlaunchapplicationnotification

Comment: @jnpdx thanks, post it as an answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to events (such as `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification`) via `NotificationCenter`. See the following documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspacedidlaunchapplicationnotification

In particular, look at the **See also -> Responding to Environment Notifications section**, which lists many relevant notifications to this task.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not work currently(
2022.08 ) -
change.oldValue & change.newValue at the moment IS EMPTY because of bug https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20757

but must work in future

```
class StatsCollector {
    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation
    
    init() {
        self.observer = NSWorkspace.shared
            .observe(\.runningApplications, options: [.initial]) { (model, change) in
                //some code
            }
    }
}
```